# A Semi-Generic Check if Null, Replace with Default Function in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking for a way to make a generic function of this operation:

```
SomeObject object = (object != null) ? object : SomeObject.default();
```

Assume `SomeObject.default()` returns a default instance of SomeObject.

I'm thinking I would need an interface like:

```
public interface Defaultable {
     public /* static */ Defaultable default(); //corrected
}
```

And a function like:

```
public Defaultable defaultIfNull(Defaultable someOb){
    return (someOb != null) ? someOb : Defaultable.default();
}
```

Except that last function call will fail because we want the static method of the concrete class, not the interface.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: did your interface compile ?? AFAIK Interfaces cannot have static methods.

Comment: I didn't compile any of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really - the `null` that gets passed as the parameter doesn't have any type information. You cannot do it with a generic factory, since for that you will need to have the type at hand to get the proper factory object.

On the third hand, *why* do you need this pattern?

Comment: I don't *need* it for this particular example. This is kind of a thought experiment, but I often find myself wanting to generalize in similar ways and running into java's you can't pass a function wall.

Comment: Of course you can pass a function, but it must be wrapped in an inner class. (Or you could wait for lambdas, but that is ~11 months away...)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> T replaceIfNull(T objectToCheck, T defaultValue) {
    return objectToCheck == null ? defaultValue : objectToCheck;
}

replaceIfNull(getXdata(),BigDecimal.ZERO).add(getYdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the static from the interface. It's not needed.

Comment: though its correct, it isn't an answer. please post it under comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public <T> T firstNonNull(T ... vals) {
   // omitted
}
```

It's not exactly what you want, but more general (and works).

Answer (score 0):

step by step implementation:

step1

```
public abstract class Defaultable {

public abstract  Defaultable defaultMethod();

public Defaultable defaultIfNull(Defaultable someOb){
    return (someOb != null) ? someOb : defaultMethod();
}
```

}

step 2

```
public class DefImpl extends Defaultable{       
@Override
public  DefImpl defaultMethod() {       
            return new DefImpl();
}
```

}

step 3

```
Defaultable def = new DefImpl();
def.defaultIfNull(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it non-static like this:

```
public interface Defaultable {
     public Defaultable default(Defaultable someOb); 
}
```

And an implementation like:

```
public Defaultable defaultIfNull(Defaultable someOb){
    return (someOb != null) ? someOb :this; // Return myself if the provided is null
}
```

You would call it like so:

```
return new DefaultableImpl().defaultIfNull(someObject);
```